# Always end up losing Settings app in the Dash

Tags: 22.04, unity-dash, settings

I have Ubuntu 22.04 installed on a spare hard drive, but I always encounter a problem where the Settings app ceases to exist in the Dash after a while. This has happened on virtual machines on Windows and the actual OS installed on my computer's spare hard drive.

[image]

The image is the search for settings in Ubuntu where it just stopped appearing. When I first installed Ubuntu 22.04 everything was normal and the Settings app was there, but after a while it just stopped appearing even though I had not deleted anything. I plan on using this OS on a laptop for school, but I can't because this stuff always happens. Ubuntu is not running off a live USB, it is installed, so anything I do is saved for the next time I use it.

Comment: On a *live* system, nothing is saved unless you have setup the system with *persistence* which requires a specific write/creation as the default is *no persistence*.  Ubuntu 22.04 LTS is still somewhat vague; there are Desktop, Server & main *flavors* - though picture implies you mean Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Desktop - but it's best if you're specific.

Comment: sorry im not used to having to mension if im using im used to windows yes it is a desktop system if you go to downloads just the regular version of 22.04 lts again can't check settings because it doesn't exist if there is anymore information that is needed let me know

Comment: Please review my edit. I cut out the fluffy fluff. Except for the disappearing Pomeranian lap dog everything else is still normal.

Answer (score 0):

Reinstall the Ubuntu desktop environment package (*ubuntu-desktop*). Open the terminal and type.

```
sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop
sudo reboot
```